# Save input fields in another table in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

**So what i have right now:** 
a CRUD application: a Registration table and form, and an Extraregistration table where i want to save some of the fields from the registration.
The Extraregistration table has a registration_id.

**RegistrationController**

```
$registration->ris_firstname = $request->firstname;
$registration->ris_lastname= $request->lastname;
$registration->ris_email = $request->email;
```

**html**

```
<label>Firstname</label>
<input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" class="form-control" data-blocked="<>{}" value="{{ ($cache['firstname'] ?? old('firstname') ?? $registration->ris_firstname ?? '') }}"  required>

<label>Lastname</label>
<input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" class="form-control" data-blocked="<>{}" value="{{ ($cache['lastname'] ?? old('lastname') ?? $registration->ris_lastname ?? '') }}"  required>

<label>E-mail</label>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" data-blocked="<>{}" value="{{ ($cache['email'] ?? old('email') ?? $registration->ris_email ?? '') }}"  required>
```

**ExtraregistrationController**

```
$extraregistration->iea_price = $request->price;
$extraextraregistration->iea_registration_id = $registration_id;
```

**html**

```
<label>Price</label>
<input type="text" name="price" id="price" class="form-control" data-blocked="<>{}" value="{{ ($cache['price'] ?? old('price') ?? $extraregistration->iea_price ?? '') }}"  required>
```

I want to save the firstname and lastname to the extraregistration table, and not in the normal registration table.
so when i add a registration, the firstname and lastname go to the extraregistration table, in the registration_firstname field that is in the Extraregistration table in the database
Thanks in advance!

Comment: please give your Modal & blade file??& clarify your problem properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In RegisterController inside create function.

```
$extraregistration = new YourModel();
$extraregistration->ris_firstname = $request->firstname;
$extraregistration->ris_lastname= $request->lastname;
$extraregistration->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change DB structure first.
Then

Register the user. The object will be having an "id" after saving

```
$registration = new Registration();
$registration->ris_email = $request->email;
$registration->save();
```

Then create extra user data object and use the id from the registration object.

```
$extraregistration = new ExtraRegistration();
$extraregistration->ris_firstname = $request->firstname;
$extraregistration->ris_lastname= $request->lastname;
$extraregistration->iea_price = $request->price;
$extraextraregistration->iea_registration_id = $registration->id;
$extraregistration->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the first name and last name directly into `Extraregistration` table if you have a field in your database. (Extraregistration table).

```
$extraregistration = new Extraregistration();
$extraregistration->registration_firstname = $request->firstname;
$extraregistration->registration_lastname = $request->lastname;
$extraregistration->save();
```

OR

If you have not specifically field in the `Extraregistration` table then used `foreign key` like `registration_id`.

When storing registration data you need to store newly created `registration_id` into 
`Extraregistration` table like:

```
$registration = new Registration();
$registration->ris_email = $request->email;
$registration->save();

$extraregistration->iea_price = $request->price;
$extraextraregistration->iea_registration_id = $registration->id;
$extraregistration->save();
```